# TomTom Category search API does not return Phone numbers

Tags: api, flutter, tomtom

The Category search API does not return the phone numbers as specified in the documentation.
https://developer.tomtom.com/search-api/search-api-documentation-search/category-search

Screenshot of : [Category search documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khSXU.png)

The API call:

```
 https://api.tomtom.com/search/2/categorySearch/hospital.JSON?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&lat=xx.xx647&lon=xx.91026
```

Screenshot of : [Api call result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E89ne.png)

**I need phone numbers from the hospitals near the given latitude and longitude values.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all POIs contain phone number. So it is a matter of stored data in TT services.

Comment: It was for hospitals in a given area. Are you saying hospitals won't have phone number data stored in the API?

Comment: That could be the case.